# How do I use Bluetooth earphones as a high-quality stereo audio device in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

The device that I'm using is the Signature-VMB47.

My Bluetooth 'headset' has these services enabled:

[image: Signature-VMB47 properties services window]

Now, through Googling, I've come to know that I need to enable Audio Sink for my device to transmit high quality audio to my headset. But when I try checking the box, I get this:

`The specified service does not exist as an installed service.`

[image: Signature-VMB47 properties services window with error message]

What should I do now? Right now, I'm only getting 'telephony' level audio.

[image: Headset properties window with audio format of Telephone Quality]

I'm okay with not being able to use my microphone simultaneously.

Comment: Check the Windows system event log if it contains an entry that contains more details which service is missing.

Comment: Try completely removing the Bluetooth pairing and then doing it again.

Comment: Right-click on audio icon in system tray, then click 'Sounds' from the list.
Now go to 'Playback' tab and look for your Bluetooth earphones there.
Check if they are disabled.

Comment: @NetServOps No, they are not.

Comment: @DanielB Yep, tried that multiple times.